# html cannot display image in django

Tags: html, django, image, src

I have put my image file **img.png** and HTML file **index.html** in the same folder **test** 
I executed **index.html** in django, I wanted to display image from local

I tried

```
<img src='img.png'/>
```

```
<img src='./img.png'/>
```

```
<img src='..../test/img.png'/>   <!-- absolute path -->
```

the system all says cannot find the image file.

Comment: Could you post the system error. What's written in the browser console?

Comment: Have you tried `<img src='/img.png'/>` or `<img src='/test/img.png'/>`?

Comment: Why would you put an image in your templates folder?

Comment: I tried to upload image in media url which set in settings, but failed to upload. Then I tried to use the basic file uploads in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/
which can success to upload and process the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

2-In your settings file, define STATIC_URL, for example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

3-In your templates, use the static template tag to build the URL for the given relative path using the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'my_app/example.jpg' %}" alt="My image">
```

4-Store your static files in a folder called static in your app.
For example:
my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg.